# Htaccess redirect specific page and querystring variable

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a redirect with a .htaccess file matching these specific requirement:

1. The page/script name is **foo.php**
2. The querystring must contain **p=1**
3. There could be any number of other querystring variables present

If these conditions are met, you should be redirected to: /new-url/

This is what I've come up with that doesn't work. It matches and redirects /foo.php but not /foo.php?p=1 or /foo.php?p=1&x=5

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^foo\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . new-url/? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)foo\.php$ /new-url/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also test it in a different browser to avoid browser caching issues due to `R=301`